# Bootstrap 3 without Glyphicons replaced with Font Awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons

I want to remove Bootstrap 3 Glyphicons in favor of Font Awesome. Since Font Awesome already includes most of the Glyphicons y don't want to include them and avoid duplicates and compatibility problems.

when I make a customized bootstrap download and I uncheck the glyphicon component, I still see some glyphicon references on the css file. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

How can I disable those icons entirely ?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those 6 remaining Glyphicons references in the compiled CSS are regarding the optional use of Glyphicons for the next+prev buttons in the Carousel component. Since the declarations in question are also used for the non-Glyphicon next+prev buttons and represent an absolutely trivial amount of the total file size, I suggest simply ignoring them. For all practical purposes, you've already eliminated Glyphicons from your build.

If you absolutely must annihilate said references, then [compile Bootstrap manually](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#compiling-css-and-javascript), beforehand removing the offending lines from `bootstrap/less/carousel.less` and removing the `@import "glyphicons.less";` line from `bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less`.
Or you can just manually edit the CSS that the Bootstrap Customizer already generated for you, since the relevant deletions are trivial.

Answer (score 4):

As i use bootstrap with Font Awesome, i go to customize page and I unchecked the glyphicon component as you did, but for some time i also **add this lines of code** at my ( override file ):

```
[class^="icon-"],
[class*="icon-"] {
  background: none;
}
```

also you can open the main bootstrap file that you downloaded ( customized one ) and search for `font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';` , then comment all the `@font-face`.

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 4):

Solution for [less](http://lesscss.org/) (tested for bootstrap 3.3.5):

First, override icons for carousel:

```
// Overloading "glyphicon" class with "fa".
.glyphicon
{

    &:extend(.fa);

    // Overloading "glyphicon-chevron-left" with "fa-arrow-left".
    &.glyphicon-chevron-left
    {
        &:extend(.fa-chevron-left);
    }

    // Overloading "glyphicon-chevron-right" with "fa-arrow-right".
    &.glyphicon-chevron-right
    {
        &:extend(.fa-chevron-right);
    }
}
```

This part is taken from [Slava Fomin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26638216/1115187), based on Steven Clontz's  [base code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2475#issuecomment-49469969).

Next step: disable glyphicons loading:

```
//** Load fonts from this directory.
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
//** File name for all font files.
@icon-font-name:          "fontawesome-webfont";
//** Element ID within SVG icon file.
@icon-font-svg-id:        "fontawesomeregular";
```

Do not forget about lessc [lazy loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading): `@icon-font-svg-id` and other vars will have the latest value you have set.

Comment: Over here you can find a SCSS variant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638215/how-to-replace-glyphicons-with-fontawesome-in-bootstrap-3-without-changing-html